# Interacting Brownian particles via harmonic repulsive potential

Tags: differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Following this paper (DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevResearch.1.032038) I want to simulate thermally driven particles in a viscous fluid that interact via the harmonic repulsive potential in 2D, namely 
$V(r_{ij}) = -\frac{\varepsilon}{2\sigma_0^2}(\sigma_{ij}-r_{ij})^2\Theta(\sigma_{ij}-r_{ij})$,
where $r_{ij}$ is the distance between the particles $i$ and $j$, and $\sigma_{ij} = (\sigma_i+\sigma_j)/2$, where $\sigma_i$ is the diameter of particle $i$.

 $\Theta(x)$ is the Heavyside step function.  
So far, I've tried playing around having particles moving in a external potential via the `ItoProcess` function:

```
potential = 2 (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2);
ito = 
ItoProcess[{\[DifferentialD]x[t] == -D[potential, x[t]] \[DifferentialD]t 
+ \[DifferentialD]w1[t], 
    \[DifferentialD]y[t] == -D[potential, y[t]] \[DifferentialD]t 
+ \[DifferentialD]w2[t]}, {x[t], 
    y[t]}, {{x, y}, {x0, y0}}, t, {w1 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], 
    w2 \[Distributed] WienerProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]}];
```

From that, I get the trajectories for `n` particles as

```
size = 2;
time = 10;
frq = 10^-1;
sigma = 0.1;
path = Table[
   RandomFunction[
    ito /. {x0 -> RandomReal[{-size, size}], 
      y0 -> RandomReal[{-size, size}], \[Mu] -> 0, \[Sigma] -> 
      sigma}, {0, time, frq}, 1], {i, n}];
```

The authors of the paper employed the over dampened Langevin equation: 
$\eta \frac{\partial \vec{r}_i}{\partial t}= -\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{\partial V(r_{ij})}{\partial \vec{r}_j}+\vec{\xi}_i(t)$, 
where $\eta$ is the dampening coefficient, $\vec{r}_i$ is the position of particle $i$ and $\vec{\xi}$ is the thermal agitation noise, following the fluctuation dissipation theorem as 
$\langle \vec{\xi}_i(t) \vec{\xi}_j(t')^T\rangle = 2T\eta\delta_{ij} \mathbb{1}\delta(t-t')$

Would it be possible to implement this problem via the `ItoProcess` function as well?

How would one implement the particle - particle interactions best? Perhaps a matrix formulation of the scattering potential would be of help here? I am still somewhat new to the whole topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a really brute force way for now. Let me know what could be improved computationally wise.
Setting the radius and defining the potential

```
r0 = 1;
V[x1_, x2_, y1_, 
   y2_] := (r0 - 
      Sqrt[Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2]^2 + 
        Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2]^2])^2 HeavisideTheta[(r0 - 
      Sqrt[Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2]^2 + Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2]^2])];
```

Calculating the associated forces

```
fx[\[FormalX]1_, \[FormalX]2_, \[FormalY]1_, \[FormalY]2_] = -D[
    V[\[FormalX]1, \[FormalX]2, \[FormalY]1, \[FormalY]2], \
\[FormalX]1];
fy[\[FormalX]1_, \[FormalX]2_, \[FormalY]1_, \[FormalY]2_] = -D[
    V[\[FormalX]1, \[FormalX]2, \[FormalY]1, \[FormalY]2], \
\[FormalY]1];
```

Number of particles and associated particle particle indices (`i!=j`)

```
n = 50;
forceperm = 
  ArrayReshape[
   Flatten[Permutations[Range[n], {2}], 1], {n, n - 1, 2}];
```

Defining the Ito process

```
Clear[x]
ito = ItoProcess[
 Flatten[Table[{\[DifferentialD]Symbol["x" <> ToString[j]][
       t] == (Sum[
          fx[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#[[1]]]][t], 
             Symbol["x" <> ToString[#[[2]]]][t], 
             Symbol["y" <> ToString[#[[1]]]][t], 
             Symbol["y" <> ToString[#[[2]]]][t]] &@
           forceperm[[j, i]], {i, n - 1}] + 
         f2x[Symbol["x" <> ToString[j]][t], 
          Symbol["y" <> ToString[j]][
           t]]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]Symbol[
         "w" <> ToString[j]][t], \[DifferentialD]Symbol[
        "y" <> ToString[j]][
       t] == (Sum[
          fy[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#[[1]]]][t], 
             Symbol["x" <> ToString[#[[2]]]][t], 
             Symbol["y" <> ToString[#[[1]]]][t], 
             Symbol["y" <> ToString[#[[2]]]][t]] &@
           forceperm[[j, i]], {i, n - 1}] + 
         f2y[Symbol["x" <> ToString[j]][t], 
          Symbol["y" <> ToString[j]][
           t]]) \[DifferentialD]t + \[DifferentialD]Symbol[
         "v" <> ToString[j]][t]}, {j, n}], 1], 
 Flatten@Transpose[{Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, n}], 
    Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, n}]}], {Flatten@
   Transpose[{Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}], 
     Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]}], 
  Flatten@Transpose[{Table[Symbol["x0" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}], 
     Table[Symbol["y0" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]}]}, t, 
 Flatten@Transpose[{Table[
     Symbol["w" <> ToString[i]] \[Distributed] 
      WienerProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {i, n}], 
    Table[Symbol["v" <> ToString[i]] \[Distributed] 
      WienerProcess[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {i, n}]}]];
```

Setting some further simulation parameters

```
size = 1;
plotrange = {{-size, size}, {-size, size}};
aimedsize = 400;
pixelsize = Differences[plotrange[[1]]][[1]]/aimedsize // N;
time = 1;
frq = 10^-3;
sigma = 1;
```

Simulation step

```
path = RandomFunction[
  ito2 /. Flatten[
    Prepend[{\[Mu] -> 0, \[Sigma] -> sigma}, 
     Join[Table[
       Symbol["x0" <> ToString[i]] -> RandomReal[{-size, size}], {i, 
        n}], Table[
       Symbol["y0" <> ToString[i]] -> RandomReal[{-size, size}], {i, 
        n}]]]], {0, time, frq}, 1]
```

Obtaining the trajectories and plotting

````
dat = Table[
   path["ValueList"][[1]][[All, {i, i + 1}]], {i, 1, 2 n, 2}];
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[Table[dat[[i]][[j]], {i, n}], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]], {j, 1, Length@dat[[1]], 1}]```
````